# Append new items in database only

Tags: python, database, syntax, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `classes`
Which has fields:

`course name`
 `times_mentioned`

So what I'm trying to do is. Set `course_name` and `times_Mentioned` to null at first.
But when a user for instance in my website chooses a class, I just want to append that class name and keep adding +1 to `times_mentioned` for a specific class.

This is what I have so far

```
class popular_courses(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, default=None)
    times_mentioned =db.Column(db.String(80), default=None, unique=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Popular Courses %r>' % (self.name) 

@app.route('/add/<coursename>')
def AddCourseName(coursename):
    addPopularCourse = popular_courses(name=coursename, times_mentioned=##DONT KNOW THE SYNTAX)
```

So like I'd want class name and add +1 every time the user visits /add URL. How would I do it? I don't know the syntax for it either.

@app.route('/add/')

```
def AddCourseName(coursename):
    try:
        addPopularCourse = popular_courses(name=coursename, times_mentioned=1)
        db.session.add(addPopularCourse)
        db.session.commit()
        return "added! " +  coursename + " to db"
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
        db.session.rollback()
        user = popular_courses.query.filter_by(name=coursename).first()
        user.name = coursename
        user.times_mentioned += 1
        db.session.commit()
```

Is this the efficient approach?

Comment: first change`times_mentioned ` type to `integer`then in views before creating model instance check if instance exist in db if so retrieve object increase counter save object else create object and assign `times_mentioned ` to 1

Comment: @HishamKaram I figured something very similar to that. I'll update my thread and if you could review it and see if it's a efficient approach!

Comment: waiting for you

Comment: wait i will write pseudo code for you

Comment: It won't add new instance becuase at my course model I made the course name to set to be unique ;)

Comment: check you question `name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, default=None)`

Comment: Hence I added exception there so if it throws me intgirity unique error; it takes the pass and updates my table instead but I'm not sure if it's a smart move.

Comment: Woops! Forgot to update it!

Comment: yeah now seems to be ok

Comment: better to check for existence `if session.query(popular_courses.id).filter(popular_courses.name==coursename).count() > 0:` instead of `try`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- change type of `times_mentioned` to `integer`

2- use `count` func to check if instance exist if so increase counter else create a new one

```
def AddCourseName(coursename):
    if db.session.query(popular_courses.id).filter(popular_courses.nam‌​e==coursename).count‌​() > 0:
        course = popular_courses.query.filter_by(name=coursename).first()
        course.name = coursename
        course.times_mentioned += 1
        db.session.commit()
        return "increased by 1! "
    else:
        addPopularCourse = popular_courses(name=coursename, times_mentioned=1)
        db.session.add(addPopularCourse)
        db.session.commit()
        return "added! " +  coursename + " to db"
```